# For what values of $a$, $b$ and $c$ is $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ (i) one-to-one? (ii) onto?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be real numbers and consider that $f$ maps $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

For what values of $a$, $b$ and $c$ is $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ (i) one-to-one? (ii) onto?

Comment: It would be great if you could show us some of the work you've done. Have you considered what shape the graphs of the functions take for different values of $a,\ b$ and $c$?

Comment: I was thinking if a = 0 and b is not equal to zero, that is one case when f is both one-to-one and onto, but i couldn't figure out how to formulate the argument when a is not equal to zero. Also i tried to do an algebraic solution but ran out of ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Informal, to give you a start:

If $a\ne 0$, what does the curve $y=ax^2+bx+c$ look like? Bad, no? It is an upward or downward opening parabola, and one can *see* that both one to one and onto fail.

So for one to one, or onto, we need $a=0$. Suppose from now on that $a=0$.

If $b=0$, big trouble.

Show that if $a=0$ and $b\ne 0$, the function is one to one and onto. Geometrically, $y=bx+c$ is a line neither up and down nor parallel to the $x$-axis.
The value of $c$ doesn't matter.

After you have figured out geometrically what's going on, doing the algebraic details (if required) will not be difficult.

Comment: thanks but as i commented above, i already knew the part when a is equal to zero. But i was not sure when a is not equal to zero but i think i agree with your claim that if a is not equal to zero then there is no chance of it being one-to-one or onto. right?

Comment: If you already knew the part when $a=0$, the time and place to acknowledge this was when you posted the question, not after someone took the time to think it through and type it out.

Comment: @UH1: If you want algebra, suppose $a\ne 0$, and set $ax^2+bx+c=y$, or equivalently $ax^2+bx+c-y=0$. Solve using the Quadratic Formula. We get something that involves $\pm\sqrt{b^2-4a(c-y)}$. Argue that there are $y$ such that the thing under the square root sign is negative, so no (real) $x$. That shows not onto. Argue also that there is a $y$ such that the thing under the square root sign is positive. Then $2$ solutions, therefore not one to one.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Thank you so much, appreciate your help a lot.

Comment: And @Gerry Myerson: You are right and I apologize for this, its just that I am new at using this forum, won't happen again. Thanks for pointing it out.